# В матрице A [i, j] m, n поменять местами строки с min и max суммами элементов в строке

Tags: c#

Проблема следующая мы создаем матрицу, задаем размерность. Дальше считаем суммы каждой строки. Определяем строку с наибольшей суммой и наименьшей сумой и меняем их местами. Строка с наибольшей суммой у меня определяется а наименьшей не получается. По коду будет видно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class _Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n, m, sum = 0, summax;

            Console.WriteLine("Введ n-рядків и m-стовбців!");
            Console.Write("n=");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("m=");
            m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            int[,] k = new int[n, m];
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Матриця: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    k[i, j] = r.Next(0, 100);

                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0,3} ", k[i, j]));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            summax = -1;
            int summin = 0;
            int rowmin = 0;
            int rowmax = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    sum += k[i, j];
                if (sum > summax)
                {
                    summax = sum;
                    rowmax = i + 1;
                }

                else 
                {
                    summin =  sum;  // ??
                    rowmin = i-1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Сума " + (i + 1) + " рядка рівна " + sum);     
                sum = 0;    
            }


                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Найбільша сума у " + rowmax + " рядку, сумма " + summax);
                Console.WriteLine("Наймеша сума у " + rowmin + " рядку, сумма " + summin);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) `int summin = 0;` => `int summin = int.MaxValue;`

Comment: 2) `if (sum < summin) {summin = sum, rowmin = i}`

Comment: Наименьшую сумму наконец определяет, спасибо. Теперь нужно те строки с минимальной и максимальной суммой поменять местами, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Начните с обмена значениями между двумя ячейками, а потом сделайте это для двух строк

Comment: Можно поподробнее, я не понял какими ячейками

Comment: напишите код, который принимает координаты двух ячеек, и меняет значения в этих ячейках местами

Comment: потом запустите этот код для 2х строк